# Strange Domain name under the same IP Address

Tags: domain-name-system

There's something really weird happening in my server.

But first things first: I wanted to have my website and chose the domain name "myowndomain.com", Now on my domain registrar I point "myowndomain.com" to the address of my recently setup VPS, let's say 50.50.50.50

So I installed everything I needed to run my website, and I started to notice strange queries coming from different IP Addresses.

Like these

```
[client 123.123.123.123] File does not exist: /var/www/html/api, referer: http://www.strangedomain.com/api/manyou/my.php
[client 456.456.456.456] File does not exist: /var/www/html/api, referer: http://www.strangedomain.com/api/manyou/my.php
```

or like this (Really a long line, I cut some things)

```
GET /?s=vod-show-id-22-area-%E5%85%B6%E4%BB%96-language-%E9%9F%A9%E8%AF%AD.html HTTP/1.1" 301 295 "http://v.strangedomain.com/?s=vod-s ...[cut]... spider"
```

That above is happening the most.

The 'strangedomain.com' returns the same IP address of my VPS which my website is hosted on. The whois of such domain shows it's registered to a chinese. But the street name didn't look so right (like a huge single word), so I think all of that info might be fake, but still might be a chinese.
I also noticed that all 'clients' trying to access the 'strangedomain.com' is coming from china.

If I type in the browser 'strangedomain.com', I see my website.

I'm worried, because my website is actually an e-commerce.
I don't know if 'strangedomain.com' WAS a website on 50.50.50.50 in the not so far past, or if it's something else.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the Internet. You will see all kinds of random junk all the time and you will always wonder whether it's an attack or just random junk. There's no shortcut. You need to investigate each case and make an intelligent determination.

If you're not qualified to do this, why are you the server administrator?

Comment: can we have this as some kind of answer-template?

Comment: I can use my second IP Address, start banning all china clients who tries to access the current ip. You didn't say what 'intelligent determination' could be.

Comment: David can't possibly teach you how to distinguish between log file junk and genuine attack attempts in an SF answer; it is a vast, complex, and rapidly-evolving field.  The true value of his answer, as written, is in the last sentence, and you would do well to heed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what to address as it's a fairly broad question but for the last part of question you could see how recent 'strangedomain.com' is by looking at the whois record for it and seeing the registration date. If you didn't want your website to be accessed through this URL you could configure your vhosts file so that it's only accessible via "myowndomain.com".